# Why it is necessary to add getter and setters of an entity to save in db using JpaRepository (SpringBoot)?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Why it is necessary to add getter and setters of an entity to save in db using JpaRepository (SpringBoot) ?

i had not set getters and setters and in entity and after saving it stores null value in table for all fields.

Comment: If you declare field-base attributes than it should not be required. see e.g. https://thorben-janssen.com/access-strategies-in-jpa-and-hibernate/. 
Otherwise you could use lombok to autogenerate getter/setter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necssary to use getter setter in entity because when spring tries to make our entity as a table in database it call setter method to set the value of field and when you are fetching the value from the database by using spring it calls the getter the method of field and you are saying that when you implemented the getter setter it stores null values in your database that may be because you are not setting any value to the field before saving it to databse if you set any value it will never store null

Comment: but when we are using field based access then what happens if those fields are private and also we haven't provided any getters or setters to the Entity ? In this scenario how will JPA access data ?